# How to use nonnull and nullable Objective-C keywords in block-based API method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nullable

Consider the following method

```
- (void)methodWithArg:(NSString *)arg1 andArg:(NSString *)arg2 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *results, NSError *error))completionHandler;
```

With the new `nonnull` and `nullable` [annotation keywords](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) we can enrich it as follows:

```
- (void)methodWithArg:(nonnull NSString *)arg1 andArg:(nullable NSString *)arg2 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *results, NSError *error))completionHandler;
```

but we also get this warning:

> Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (__nonnull or
>   __nullable)

It refers to the third parameter (the block one).

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) doesn't cover with examples how to specify the nullability of block parameters. It states verbatim

> You can use the non-underscored forms nullable and nonnull immediately
>   after an open parenthesis, as long as the type is a simple object or
>   block pointer.

I tried putting one of the two keywords for the block (in any position) without any luck. Also tried the underscore prefixed variants (`__nonnull` and `__nullable`).

Therefore my question is: how can I specify the nullability semantic for block parameters?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

This seems to be working

```
- (void)methodWithArg:(nonnull NSString *)arg1 
  andArg:(nullable NSString *)arg2 completionHandler:(nullable void (^)
  (NSArray * _Nullable results, NSError * _Nonnull error))completionHandler
```

You need to specify nullability both for the block and its parameters...

EDIT: For more information, see [Swift Blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25)

Comment: How does that work with the `NSError **` type? I can't seem to make the compiler happy.

Comment: According to the swift blog:

`The particular type NSError ** is so often used to return errors via method parameters that it is always assumed to be a nullable pointer to a nullable NSError reference.`

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25

Comment: @duhanebel The answer is given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198597/nserror-swift-and-nullability:  (NSError * _Nullable *_Nullable) error

Answer (score 40):

According to [Apple Blog ("Nullability and Objective-C")](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25),
you can use

`NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` and `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END`.

Within these regions, any simple pointer type will be assumed to be `nonnull`. Then you can just add `nullable` for nullable object, which like

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MyClass: NSObject

- (void)methodWithArg:(NSString *)arg1 andArg:(nullable NSString *)arg2 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *results, NSError *error))completionHandler;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

- if **error** is `NSError **` type, should be `NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable`
- if object is `id *` type, better use `id _Nullable * _Nonnull`, it depends (may be you want a `_Nullable id * _Nullable` type).
- if object is `NSObject *` type, you need put annotation after pointer, like this `NSObject * _Nullable * _Nonnull`

**Note**

`_Nonnull` and `_Nullable` should used after pointer or `id` (Apple does in the example code `AAPLListItem * _Nullable`), but the non-underscored forms `nonnull` and `nullable` can used after an open parenthesis.

> However, in the common case there’s a much nicer way to write these
>   annotations: within method declarations you can use the
>   non-underscored forms `nullable` and `nonnull` immediately after an open
>   parenthesis, as long as the type is a simple object or block pointer.

check more in ["Nullability and Objective-C"](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25)

> For safety, there are a few exceptions to this rule:
>
> - `typedef` types don’t usually have an inherent nullability—they can
>     easily be either nullable or non-nullable depending on the context.
>     Therefore, `typedef` types are not assumed to be `nonnull`, even within
>     audited regions.
> - More complex pointer types like `id *` must be
>     explicitly annotated. For example, to specify a non-nullable pointer
>     to a nullable object reference, use `_Nullable id * _Nonnull`.
> - The particular type `NSError **` is so often used to return errors via
>     method parameters that it is always assumed to be a nullable pointer
>     to a nullable `NSError` reference.

The `_Nullable id * _Nonnull` can be confused, `id _Nullable * _Nonnull` is better understanding.

**`_Nonnull` and `_Nullable` should used after pointer or `id` (Apple does in the example code `AAPLListItem * _Nullable`**)

Comment: For weak property, _Nullable applied.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do like this:

```
- (id __nullable)methodWithArg:(NSString * __nullable)arg1
                        andArg:(NSString * __nonnull)arg2
             completionHandler:(void (^ __nonnull)(NSArray * __nonnull results, NSError * __nullable error))completionHandler;
```

It only depends which syntax you like more.

Comment: can you elaborate just a little more on the MEANING of what you defined? Do I get it right that the code-block is REQUIRED for this method, and cannot be nil? I tried  to add the _Nonnull before the last parenthesis NSError * __nullable error) _Nonnull )completionHandler; and got a nasty compiler error for that.

Answer (score 2):

To define completions in a header file I did this

```
typedef void (^PublicEventsHandler) (BOOL success, NSArray * _Nullable publicEvents);
```

Of course, I agree with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

From apple [developer blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25): The Core: _Nullable and _Nonnull

> you can use the non-underscored forms
> nullable and nonnull **immediately after an open parenthesis**, as long as
> the type is a simple object or block pointer.
>
> The non-underscored forms are nicer than the underscored ones, but
> **you’d still need to apply them to every type in your header**.

Comment: Yeah but the non-underscore (nicer) ones don't work in block declarations

Answer (score -2):

Here is what I have used for the NSError ** case:

```
-(BOOL) something:(int)number withError:(NSError *__autoreleasing  __nullable * __nullable)error;
```

Comment: As [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) said, for `NSError **`, you have no need to specify its nullability.