# Using nullability with block based APIs

Tags: objective-c, nullable, xcode6.4

I have an API

`+ (void)getTheThing:(nonnull void (^)(NSString * __nullable thing, NSError * __nullable error))completion;`

(Syntax taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647919/how-to-use-nonnull-and-nullable-objective-c-keywords-in-block-based-api-method))

But when go to use it, and take advantage of Xcode's block autocomplete, it autocompletes to this:

```
[MyAPI getTheThing:^nonnull void(NSString * __nullable, NSError * __nullable) {
    <#code#> 
}];
```

Which gives errors for `nonnull` being not recognised, the fact there's not argument names etc...

Any idea what's going on? :S Am I declaring it wrong? This stuff is fairly new, and the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) isn't really complete :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any idea what's going on?

It is broken http://www.openradar.me/20835509

> Am I declaring it wrong?

You could annotate blocks like this:

`+ (void)getTheThing:(void (^__nonnull)(NSString * __nullable thing, NSError * __nullable error))completion;`

Then autocomplete would produce this code:

```
[MyAPI getTheThing:^(NSString * __nullable, NSError * __nullable) {
    <#code#> 
}];
```

It is still broken though. It would probably be faster just to forget about autocomplete and copy and paste your block declaration.

> This stuff is fairly new, and the documentation isn't really complete

There is more info on [llvm](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#nullability-attributes) website, but still not enough info on blocks.