# NSError, Swift, and nullability

Tags: objective-c, swift, error-handling, objective-c-nullability

I'm writing a set of tools in Objective-C that will be used by Swift at some point so I'm using generics and nullability. What am I supposed to do in this situation?

```
- (NSArray<MyObj *> * __nullable)foo:(NSError **)error;
```

Currently I'm getting a warning: *`Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier...`* for both pointers! I'm almost certain that I'm NOT to supposed to do:

```
- (NSArray<MyObj *> * __nullable)foo:(NSError * __autoreleasing __nullable * __nullable)error;
```

Am I?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Swift blog entry [Nullability and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) states:

> The particular type `NSError **` is so often used to return errors via
>   method parameters that it is always assumed to be a nullable pointer
>   to a nullable `NSError` reference.

However, this remark is listed as an exception to the rules
of "Audited Regions", and it seems that it applies only within
an audited region:

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MyClass : NSObject
- (NSArray<MyObj *> * _Nullable)foo:(NSError **)error;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Within an audited region, any simple pointer type will be assumed to be `nonnull` (with some exceptions as the above-mentioned for `NSError`).

Outside of an audited region, you actually have to write explicitly

```
- (NSArray<MyObj *> * _Nullable)foo:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error;
```

to avoid warnings about missing nullability type specifiers.

(`_Nullable` is the newer syntax used in Xcode 7 and replaces `__nullable`.)