# how to add nullable/nonnull/_NonNull/_Nullable to void *

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add nullability to the argument in the method signature. 
my method declaration look like

```
(instancetype)initWithNetworkingService(id<NetworkingService>)networkingService;
```

How do I add nullability to above method ? NetworkingService is a Protocol

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647919/how-to-use-nonnull-and-nullable-objective-c-keywords-in-block-based-api-method

Comment: I tried `- (instancetype)initWithNetworkingService: (id<NetworkingService>) _Nonnull networkingService;` and `- (instancetype)initWithNetworkingService: (nullable id<NetworkingService>) networkingService;` nothing seems to be working

'